# $n$ points, $n$ connections - is there a guaranteed cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Suppose we have $n$ points and $n$ lines connecting two points. Is there always going to be a sequence of connections that is cycled and we can get back to the same point?

Ex: A-B, B-C, C-A would be a cycle.

I have no idea how to solve it, I have no idea how to approach this problem, I'm a high school student doing contest math.

This is not a problem, it's just something I struggled with a few times while proving things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. If there were no cycle, you would have the kind of graph known as a *forest*, one whose connected components are [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Definitions). A tree always has one more node (or vertex — what you’ve called a point) than it has edges (lines connecting two nodes), so a forest of $k$ trees has $k$ more nodes than edges. In particular, a forest cannot have as many edges as it has nodes. [This PDF](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_trees_17-handout.pdf) introduces trees and includes a proof that a tree with $n$ nodes has $n-1$ edges.

Comment: If I were to write 'A tree or a branching of n nodes has n-1 edges, hence if we add one more line we will have at least one cycle.' Is this a sufficent proof? How do we account if there were two disjoint sets of connected points or something? Greatly appreciated

Comment: @Danjel: You don’t have to argue in that direction at all. By definition the connected acyclic graphs — the connected graphs without cycles — are precisely the trees, and we have the theorem that a tree with $n$ nodes always has exactly $n-1$ edges. An acyclic graph doesn’t have to be connected, but if it’s not, then it’s a union of some finite number of disjoint trees. Suppose that it’s composed of $t$ trees, having $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_t$ nodes, respectively, for a total of $n_1+\ldots,n_t=n$ nodes. Then it has $$(n_1-1)+(n_2-2)+\ldots+(n_t-1)=(n_1+\ldots+n_t)-t=n-t$$ edges. In particular, ...

Comment: ... $n-t<n$, so it definitely does not have the same number of edges and nodes. It follows immediately that a graph that **does** have the same number of edges and nodes cannot be acyclic and therefore must contain a cycle.